# ADFS SSO in UWP App

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, office365, azure-active-directory, adfs

I am facing a hopefully simple problem:

I need to create a wrapper app that contains a `WebViewer` control and should display a page in Azure portal.

I am developing the app in VS 2017 on a virtual machine which belongs to the domain 'DEV'. I would like to achieve that if a user from 'PROD' domain starts the app on their computer in the 'PROD' domain, they will be authenticated to AAD/Office 365 via SSO and can view the page in Azure (not a site in azurewebsites.net, but a site that needs you to be authenticated - i.e. portal.azure.com!).

I was not yet able to test the app on 'PROD' domain, but according to the answer below it would work, wouldn't it?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9593258

If not can I go through the steps in the white paper mentioned and SSO the user manually (chapter 5.3, I assume)?

**EDIT**

Took me while, but here it is - I got SSO working, sort of...
In the end it seems that using a `WebViewer` control allows SSO but it still requires you to at least once enter your user name (user@tenant.com, for example) but you don't need a password. This might not be an optimal solution, nevertheless it is OK.

Thank you Wayne Yang for your support.

Comment: Um... I'm not 100% sure. It should depends on how your App works with ADFS. E.g. if your app is a Claims aware application which means use other protocols like WS-federation, it should can be SSO in other domian. If your app is not a claim aware application, which means it uses keberos to SSO, it may not be SSO in other domain.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My hope was simply that I could browse a site in the Azure portal without asking users for credentials. I have not implemented any logic that performs a login because I am just using a `WebViewer` control which, in turn, should just be I.E./Edge.

Comment: I got that.  I assume that it should can SSO into the `PROD `domain if the domain was joined AAD and integrated with ADFS.

Comment: I will come back at you as soon as I was able to test it in PROD domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your sceanrio,  the user can SSO in PROD domain if the device has AAD joined.
But this should SSO to the joined AAD tenant. I also assume that you want to SSO to Azure portal with the ADFS. So, it also needs integrate ADFS with the AAD.

**Why?**

First, if your application try to sign in Azure portal via pop-up a broswer, and it needs SSO. AAD join can achieve this. If a device joined AAD, it will obtain a refresh token to your device. For windows 10 , IE and Edge can use the refresh token to SSO AAD endpoint.

Second, If you want to use ADFS, you must integrate ADFS with Azure AD. In this way, AAD authentication endpoint will redirect to your ADFS to approach SSO with your local domain.

**Reference:**

[How to configure hybrid Azure Active Directory joined devices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/device-management-hybrid-azuread-joined-devices-setup)

[**Federate multiple instances of Azure AD with single instance of AD FS**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnectfed-single-adfs-multitenant-federation)

[Azure AD Connect and federation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnectfed-whatis)

Hope this helps!